# Entity framework 4 TPT strang generated SQL query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have an EF 4 data model with TPT mapping.
I have a strange behaviour about the generated SQL of a query .
Lets say entity A is a base entity , A has two derived entities B and C , also A has many associations with other entities (say E,D).
When I make a simple select on A , Context.A.First() , I profiled the generated SQL from this entity and it has all the joins with the other entities.

Do you have a ny suggestion why this happen ? fixes ? any tip.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

`Context.A` is the set of all `A` entities - including all `B` and `C` entities because every `B` and `C` *is an* `A`. It is not the set of all `A` entities that are *not* a `B` or `C`.

Therefore, if you request the first `A` in the database by `Context.A.First()` it *could* be a `B` or `C` or just an `A`. To find the concrete type of that first `A` the only way with TPT inheritance is to check if there are related records in the `B` or `C` table that have the same primary key like the first record in the `A` table. If there are related records this `A` is of type `B` (or `C`) and all column values from the record in table `B` (or `C`) have to be loaded together with the column values from the base record in table `A` in order to materialize an entity object of the correct type `B` (or `C`). If there are no related records in table `B` or `C` the concrete type is just an `A`.

In any case a join to the related `B` or `C` tables is required to figure out if there is a record or not and to determine the concrete type of the first `A`.

So, the joins you are seeing are expected behaviour when you use TPT inheritance and you can't avoid them. It has a negative impact on performance, yes, which is the biggest downside of TPT modeling.

Comment: Ok this really obvious , but why it makes joins with e and d they are related entities not like A and B

Comment: @Wasim: Do you see the join with E and D in the same query that you profiled? Or is it a second (and third) later query? When you really only run the query `Context.A.First()` I can only inmagine that *lazy loading* causes a second (and third) query.

Comment: This is really the strange behavior , I do this in the same query and lazy loading is turned of . Do you have any suggestion to profile EF query generation expressions.

Comment: @Wasim: I don't know how to profile expressions, only how to profile the SQL. I've just tested an example with a class `A`, a derived class `B` and another class `D` where `A` has a collection of `D`s. I cannot reproduce the query you describe. The SQL I get when calling `context.As.First()` only contains the expected left outer join to `B`, but no join to table `D`. Maybe you must show the details of your model and the generated SQL to make the problem reproducable.

Comment: Hi , I made some investigations. E,D were associated to A by 0..1 link, when I modified it ot 1..1 , suddenly the unnecessary joins were removed !!!!!!